# Cannot set input into parameter Coordinate_System using arcpy.AddGeometryAttributes

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system, arcmap, geometry, error-000622

I have a feature class of points: `AL_CB_Parcel_Intersect`. This feature class is already in `GCS_WGS_1984`. I am trying to use `arcpy.AddGeometryAttributes` to create X, Y attributes, but I keep getting this error:

> ExecuteError: ERROR 000622: Failed to execute (Add Geometry
>   Attributes). Parameters are not valid. ERROR 000628: Cannot set input
>   into parameter Coordinate_System.

This works in ArcMap.

What am I doing wrong in my script?

```
import arcpy
import os
parcels_dir = r"...\Processed"
stateabb = {'Alabama': 'AL',....}

coord_sys = "GCS_WGS_1984"

for k, v in stateabb.items():
if k == 'Alabama':
    print(k)
    parcel_gdb = "{}.gdb".format(k)
    parcel_cent = "{}_CB_Parcel_Intersect".format(v)
    parcel_path = os.path.join(parcels_dir, parcel_gdb)
    parcel_feat = os.path.join(parcel_path, parcel_cent)
    arcpy.env.workspace = parcel_path
    arcpy.AddGeometryAttributes_management(parcel_feat, "POINT_X_Y_Z_M", "", "", coord_sys)
    print("{} is done!".format(parcel_cent))
```

Comment: Why specify it at all if the data's already in the coordinate system that you want? I think that "coord_sys" is still just a string.

Comment: Thanks. All the below solutions worked and it also seemed to work fine if I just left out the coord system (it automatically put it in the coord sys of the feature class (which was already WGS_1984).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since your feature class is in `GCS_WGS_1984`, you don't need to specify any Coordinate System. Though, if you want to add `coord_sys` explicitly, you can use one of those:

- EPSG code as string e.g. "4326"
- EPSG code as integer e.g. 4326
- `SpatialReference` object

```
# as string
arcpy.AddGeometryAttributes_management(parcel_feat, "POINT_X_Y_Z_M", "", "", "4326")
#OR as integer
arcpy.AddGeometryAttributes_management(parcel_feat, "POINT_X_Y_Z_M", "", "", 4326)

#OR as SpatialReference object 
coord_sys = arcpy.SpatialReference(4326) # EPSG:4326 -> GCS_WGS_1984
arcpy.AddGeometryAttributes_management(parcel_feat, "POINT_X_Y_Z_M", "", "", coord_sys)
```

Comment: I tried in ArcGIS 10.2.2. I guess it's the same in other 10.x versions.

Comment: Thanks, this works and I chose it as using `coord_sys = arcpy.SpatialReference(4326)` was the easiest solution.

Answer (score 7):

Another way is to specify the spatial Reference by name, for instance, `Geographic Coordinate Systems/World/WGS 1984`.

The following snippet tested on ArcGIS 10.5 and worked as expected:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
ws = env.workspace = r"F:\Ahmad\Test\PT"
fc = "Cities.shp"

sr = arcpy.SpatialReference("Geographic Coordinate Systems/World/WGS 1984")
geom = arcpy.AddGeometryAttributes_management(fc, "POINT_X_Y_Z_M","","",sr)
```

Here is the output:

[image]

`POINT_X` and `POINT_Y` are the new geometry columns added by the code above. As you can see, it is exactly the same coordinates specified in `LATITUDE` and `LONGITUDE` columns defined already.

Answer (score 5):

The only thing I can guess is that the coordinate system parameter needs to be a coordinate system data type. You're passing a string "`GCS_WGS_1984`", however, the [documentation](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.6/tools/data-management-toolbox/add-geometry-attributes.htm) states that it should be a coordinate system instead.

Try modifying your code to declare coord_sys as follows:

```
coord_sys = arcpy.SpatialReference(4326)
```

The sample code in the documentation is a bit ambiguous, because they're setting the coordinate system to an empty string. However, before that, they set the environment coordinate system explicitly to the coordinate system of the input features. You could try that too. You could try getting the coordinate system of your feature class and then set it in the code to be the same.

Comment: `arcpy.SpatialReference("GCS_WGS_1984")` throws an error in v10.2.2.

Comment: Thanks. That's weird. It seems to work with other coordinate systems. I've modified my answer to use the factory code.